# How to make same ssid's not to interfere each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ssid

My machine is configured with 2 Access points  with same SSID's

1. Aruba Ap
2. Hostapd (wlan0_0 )

Whenever my machine connects to Aruba client is supposed to connect Aruba AP 
if not it should connect to softAp

For that I did port down of hostapd say wlan0_0 down whenever we connects to Aruba. But the problem is after I reset the connection to Aruba, client is not connecting to aruba  and it has been observed that Even the hostapd port was down it is sending probe response  and at  the time of authentication it is faling..As the SSId of the aruba and hostpad are same it client is  not connecting to both that means hostapd is interfering with the Aruba. So can you please help me how to use same ssid  with no interference ......

Answer (score -1):

Here are some options:

- Have one router use DHCP, and the other use Static IP
- Have one router use 2.4ghz, and the other use 5ghz
- Have one router use AES, and the other use TKIP